# Getting error [vite] Internal server error: [postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config') when creating a vite@latest react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, vitest

When I run `npm create vite@latest example -- --template react` to create a new project after running npm install and npm run dev I get that error, it doesn't seem to matter if I use different vite build commands, any help would be appreciated. thank you.

I am expecting to be able to just run vite to create project and have it working out of the box.

Comment: Please provide the full output of any error messages you are seeing. You reference "that error" without specifying what the error is.

You also don't detail any other steps you have tried. Please be more specific.

Comment: [vite] Internal server error: [postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
  Plugin: vite:css
  File: /Users/malik/Desktop/Programs/wordle-clone/src/App.css:undefined:undefined
      at getTailwindConfig (/Users/malik/Desktop/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:84:63)
      at /Users/malik/Desktop/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:96:92
      at /Users/malik/Desktop/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/processTailwindFeatures.js:46:11
      at plugins (/Users/malik/Desktop/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/index.js:38:63)

Comment: I have tried deleting the node modules folder and reinstall dependencies